# An open set which does not belong to Uniform Topology of $R^w$ but belongs to $l^2$ topology of $R^w $

Tags: general-topology

I can not find an open set which does not belong to Uniform Topology of $R^w$ but belongs to $l^2$ topology of $R^w $.

I know that $l^2$ topology of $R^w $ contains Uniform Topology of $R^w$. But I can not find those sets which make $l^2$ topology of $R^w $ bigger than Uniform Topology of $R^w$.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Try the unit ball of $l^2$.

Comment: What do u mean by Unit Ball? Is it the ball around the sequence whose all elements are $0$? @NateEldredge

Comment: Yes.  In other words, the set of all sequences $x$ satisfying $\sum |x(n)|^2 < 1$.  Note that there are sequences of arbitrarily small uniform norm which are not contained in this ball.

Comment: I am finding an open set which belongs to $l^2$ but does not belong to Uniform Topology of $R^w$ @NateEldredge

Comment: If that is not what you're looking for, then I don't understand your question.  The set I gave is open in $l^2$, i.e. it is an element of the $l^2$ topology, but it is not open in the uniform topology.  So it proves that the $l^2$ topology does not equal the uniform topology.  If that is not what you are looking for then please explain your question more precisely.

Comment: Yea I got it.. I did not read it properly..

Comment: Can you write a rigorous answer which would help the other viewers ?@NateEldredge

Comment: How about if you write the answer?  I think it would be good practice for you.

Answer (score 1):

As Nate Eldredge(https://math.stackexchange.com/users/822/nate-eldredge)  mentioned , the unit ball i.e the set of all sequences $x$ satisfying  $∑|x(n) |^2<1$ can be an example. 
There are sequences of arbitrarily small uniform norm which are not contained in this ball.

So this is an open ball around the zero sequence in $l^2$ which is not so in the Uniform Topology. As open ball around zero sequence of radius $1$ will look like $B(0,1)=⋃_{δ<1 }U(0,δ)$  where $U(0,δ)  = (-δ , δ) \times (-δ , δ) \times...........$
.